# Using shapeless scala to merge the fields of two different case classes

Tags: scala, shapeless

I want to merge the fields of two different case classes into a single case class.

For example, if I have the following case classes:

```
case class Test(name:String, questions:List[Question], date:DateTime)

case class Answer(answers:List[Answers])
```

I want a concise shapeless way to merge both into:

```
TestWithAnswers(name:String, questions:List[Question], date:DateTime, answers:List[Answer]).
```

Is there a nice shapeless answer out there?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use shapeless `Generic` to do this.

```
val t: Test = ???
val a: Answer = ???
val gt = Generic[Test]
val ga = Generic[Answer]
val gta = Generic[TestWithAnswers]

val ta = gta.from(gt.to(t) ++ ga.to(a))
```

or well, if you have a thing for one-liners

```
val ta = Generic[TestWithAnswers].from(Generic[Test].to(t) ++ Generic[Answer].to(a))
```

Provided `t` is an instance of `Test` and `a` is an instance of `Answer`, `ta` will be an instance of `TestWithAnswers`.

A quick explanation: `Generic` can convert a case class to and from a generic `HList` representation. So, given the structure of your classes, you can simply convert both test and answer to an hlist, concatenate the two lists into a single one and build a `TestWithAnswers` instance from it.

Here's a simpler example, which you can copy-paste and try in a REPL

```
import shapeless._
case class A(a: Int)
case class B(a: String)
case class AB(a: Int, b: String)
Generic[AB].from(Generic[A].to(A(42)) ++ Generic[B].to(B("foo")))
// AB(42, "foo")
```

Comment: do you mean val ta = gta.from(gt.to(t) ++ at.to(a)) instead of val ta = gta.from(gt.to(t) ++ gt.to(a))? Even when i make that change, the code still doesn't compile. Looks like ++ operator isn't a member of gt.to(t). any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: Also thanks for the explanation of Generic. Very helpful.

Comment: @azuras, yes that typo has already been fixed. Have you imported all shapeless? I ran the code in a repl and it worked

Comment: Yep, you are certainly right. Intellij was displaying an error but the repl has it as correct! Thanks for your help. Very nice solution

Comment: Suppose if we want to get like this . 
```TestWithAnswers(name:String, questions:List[Question], answers:List[Answer])```  . How can we do ?