# Scala - create case class with all fields from 2 other case classes

Tags: scala, types, type-conversion, shapeless

Say I have 2 case classes:

```
case class Basic(id: String, name) extends SomeBasicTrait
case class Info (age: Int, country: String, many other fields..) extends SomeInfoTrait
```

and want to create a case class that has all fields from both of those case classes. This is a possible way:

```
case class Full(bs: Basic, meta: Info) extends SomeBasicTrait with SomeInfoTrait {
 val id = bs.id
 val name = bs.name
 val age = meta.age
 val country = meta.country
 // etc
}
```

But it's a lot of boilerplate code. Is there any way to avoid this?

I couldn't find a way to achieve this in Shapeless but maybe there is..

[**Update**]

@jamborta 's comment helps and is basically this:

```
case class FullTwo(id: String, name: String, age:Int, country:String)

val b = Basic("myid", "byname")
val i = Info(12, "PT")
Generic[FullTwo].from(Generic[Basic].to(b) ++ Generic[Info].to(i))
```

The problem with this solution is that it still requires defining every field in the arguments of the `FullTwo` class, so that every time a change to `Basic` or `Info` is made, we also have to remember to change `FullTwo` as well.

Is there any way to create dynamically at compile time a case class equal to `FullTwo`?

Comment: Wouldn't this work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681784/using-shapeless-scala-to-merge-the-fields-of-two-different-case-classes

Comment: That is useful but there's still need to define every field in the new case class, i.e..`case class FullTwo(id: String, name: String, age:Int, country:String)` which means that if either Basic or Info are changed, then this would also require changing.

Comment: Are you sure you need this. Maybe you can do with `case class AB(a: A, b: B)` and lenses?

Comment: Don't really know lenses. How would that go?