# Combine instances of 2 traits to form instance of third trait

Tags: scala, shapeless

Similar to [Using shapeless scala to merge the fields of two different case classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681784/using-shapeless-scala-to-merge-the-fields-of-two-different-case-classes)
Given the following traits

```
trait A {
  val a: String
}
trait B {
  val b: String
}

trait AB extends A with B
```

Is it possible to do something like this ?

```
val q = new A { val a = "a" }
val w = new B { val b = "b" } 
val e = combine(A, B) // Returns type AB
```

It seems like if it were all case classes then I could do it with shapeless Generic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done by a normal function. With case classes, you know that you are merely storing values and that these values are already computed, they are not something like `lazy val` or `def` which can fail if you run them, and shapeless can build on top of this assumption to safely repack these values into some other structures, that are easy to combine.

If you want to do the same with traits, and return some `A with B` you would have to basically build a macro that takes `A` instance, `B` instance, and combines them - which would have a lot of corner cases (like, what if both traits have the same methods/values names but of different result types? Or what if both have the same value with the same name - which should be used?).

Unfortunately, I cannot find such macro anywhere, so it would have to be written. Most people would just merge these traits manually like this:

```
val ab: A with B = new (A with B) {
  override val a: String = a.a
  override val b: String = b.b
}
```

Comment: Ya, currently the workaround I've gone for this is pretty much similar.

`class AB (a: A, b: B) extends A with B {
  override val a: String = a.a
  override val b: String = b.b
}`
and then I use `new AB(a,b)` as a combiner. The irritating part of it is that everytime I add a new field I would have to update this but atleast the compiler throws an error

Comment: This is actually a problem only if you wave a lot of such cases to merge, and would like to write a generic function that would merge them for you. If you have only a couple of them you can write a specific function for each case.

Comment: Agreed. We have this pattern in our code base where we pass around a mega trait like `trait Mega extends A with B with C` and then write methods around individual traits. Was looking for a way to compose them together so I could build each of  them individually and make an instance of `Mega` though

Answer (score 1):

Shapeless can't do this. You need a macro.

`combine(A, B)` is not a valid syntax.

`A` and `B` has to be sealed.

Try

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox

trait Combine[A, B] {
  type Out
}

object Combine {
  type Aux[A, B, Out0] = Combine[A, B] { type Out = Out0 }
  def instance[A, B, Out0]: Aux[A, B, Out0] = new Combine[A, B] { type Out = Out0 }

  def mkCombine[A, B]: Combine[A, B] = macro impl[A, B]

  def impl[A: c.WeakTypeTag, B: c.WeakTypeTag](c: whitebox.Context): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    val aType = weakTypeOf[A]
    val bType = weakTypeOf[B]
    def subclasses(typ: Type) = typ.typeSymbol.asClass.knownDirectSubclasses
    val aSubclasses = subclasses(aType)
    val bSubclasses = subclasses(bType)
    val intersection = aSubclasses intersect bSubclasses

    if (intersection.size == 1)
      q"Combine.instance[$aType, $bType, ${intersection.head}]"
    else
      c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, s"intersection: $intersection")
  }
}

sealed trait A 
sealed trait B 
trait AB extends A with B

val c = Combine.mkCombine[A, B]
implicitly[c.Out =:= AB]
```